# add driver for a shapekey via python?

Tags: python, animation, drivers, shape-keys

how can i add a driver for a shapekey via python?

```
shape_keys.animation_data.driver_button_add(True)
```

or

```
obj=bpy.context.active_object
obj.driver_add('key_blocks["Eye_left"].value')
```

The Problem is that it can't find the shape key and shape keys are getting their driver with a different method; so I'm a bit confused how it can be added by python correctly.
Sorry I'm new to Python. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
driver = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].driver_add("value")
```

Comment: Docs say driver_add() returns a FCurve object, so you don't have the driver yet: driver = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].driver_add("value").driver (https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.driver_add)