# How to add a driver via python?

Tags: python, drivers

I want to add a driver to the Z location of an object via python.
After reading the docs and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13905/599), I would guess something like this:

```
bpy.context.object.driver_add("location", index=2)
```

However when run in the python console it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: driver_add() takes no keyword arguments
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message gives a hint:

`TypeError: driver_add() takes no keyword arguments`

So pass the index as positional argument:

`bpy.context.object.driver_add("location", 2)`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is it a mistake in the [docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=driver_add#bpy.types.bpy_struct.driver_add) then that the keyword is included?

Comment: It is confusing. The python api documentation uses templates provided by sphinx. This notation indicates that the second parameter is optional and also specifies its default value. An annotation that no keyword arguments are allowed should be added.

Comment: @pinkvertex Thanks, your comment explains why the BGE docs are like that.